# Handle dynamic number of promises in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm fetching product's data from a bunch of URLs. The result of these promises (along with product details) may contain a key called `nextPage`, which has a URL as value. I need to fetch data from that URL too. How can I wait for all the original set of promises + dynamic promises attached based on `nextPage` key ?

Currently I'm trying the following:

```js
const allUrls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
const promiseArray = [];

const getData = (url) => {
  const p = axios.get(url).then((data) => {
    if (data.nextPage) {
      // Push this into promises so that the data is not lost
      promiseArray.push(Promise.resolve(data));
      
      // There are more pages to fetch data from
      return getData(data.nextPage);
    }
    // No further pages, so return the result
    return data;
  });
  return p;
}

allUrls.forEach((url) => {
  const p = getData(url);
  promiseArray.push(p);
});

Promise.all(promiseArray).then((data) => {
// Error: data only has the value of allUrls, not dynamically added data
})
```

As I have put a comment, when the Promise.all resolves, I only get the data of original URLs put in allUrls, not the dynamically added promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time `Promise.all` is executed, `promiseArray` will only contain the promises for the product's data, not the details. You'd need to `await` each product data promise, and then push the resulting promise to the array (note that I'm using `async/await` as it allows for cleaner code):

```
for (const url of allUrls) {
   const p = await getData(url);
   promiseArray.push(p);
}
    
const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
console.log(result);
```